# WCF Data Service authorization policies

Tags: wcf, dynamic, filter, authorization, uri

I'm using the WCF Data Service and i need to implement authorization policies.
The polices are dynamic and are stored into a table that contains the target table, 
the field and the allowed value.
In order to achieve this, I override the OnStartProcessingRequest method 
of the DataService but I try to change the RequestUri I run into "Unauthorization" problem. 
There is a way to change the RequestUri parameter in OnStartProcessingRequest method?

this code generate the exeption

```
protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args) {
    Uri uri = new Uri(args.RequestUri + "?$filter=Id eq 3");
    args.RequestUri = uri;
}
```

I can't use the Interceptor because the system is dynamic and entites are unknown.

Currently the adopted solution is to apply filters in client application (html5/js) 
and verify the filtering parameters on server (into the OnStartProcessingRequest).

I wonder if there is a way for me to add filter parameters in OnStartProcessingRequest 
or any way that can fix this problem.